# Can I use Asset ID or Email ID or something else to create a link from 1 email to another?

Tags: marketing-cloud, link

We have a bilingual audience and produce two emails, English and French. I would like to be able to link to the English version from the French email similar to a view online option using %%view_email_url%%. I am wondering if we can use the Asset ID or Email ID to link to the other email?

Answer (score 0):

For needs like these, I tend to recommend making the email dynamic so that all languages are easily implemented from one. You then decide the language through a flag in a DE or whatever you want as usual, but in the email if you want to offer a different language you can overwrite the default variable by having it do a 'RequestParamter' call to fill in that variable with the language of choice to display that instead. Then you use the VAWP url and add a parameter to it which is something like `?lang=en` or `?lang=fr` and this then, when clicked will render the email in the language they chose, but will not cost a SuperMessage by directing them to a Cloudpage or similar.